# Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute width="NaN" 6d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute x="NaN"

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, bar-chart

```
    bar.append("rect")
  .attr("width", x)
  .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
   .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Hi, I am new to charting with D3. Now I am trying out many tutorials from d3.com. Now I get the 2 errors displayed in the title when trying to make a svg bar chart. Is there anyone who could help me?

Comment: You're getting "Not A Number", so clearly you're doing math with variables that aren't numbers, such as `barHeight` ?

Comment: It seems that `x(d)` is not well defined (not a number). You might want to check the function `x` (most likely a scale) and the `d` you are inputting (the data you bound to the object). Given the information provided in your example, answers are a long shot, though...

Comment: You're doing `.attr("width", x)` but also `return x(d) - 3;` so the `x` in one of these must be wrong

Comment: @adeneo 'var width = 420, barHeight = 20;' my variables should definitely be numbers..

Comment: @PinguinDirk `var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);` that's what my x variable looks like..

Comment: @Lueschee: and you are positive that `d` can be processed by `x`? (in other words: is `d` (the data bound to the object) a number that can be processed by `x`?

Comment: @PinguinDirk my data is a *.tsv file that looks like this 
`name value
Locke 4
Reyes 8
Ford 15
Jarrah 16
Shephard 23  
Kwon 42`  

I don't know what should be wrong with that..

Comment: @Lueschee you happen to have it on some jsfiddle or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when I was setting my width with a value that was `NaN`. You need to check that you are setting the `x` variable correctly. Try pasting `console.log(x)` above this line:

```
.attr("width", x)
```

and checking your console in your browser's dev tools.